# Java Type Erasure during GSON

Tags: java, gson, type-erasure

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String tr = "[{\"key\":\"foo\"}, {\"key\":\"shoe\"}]";

    List<MyClass> o = new Gson().fromJson(tr, getType());
    for (MyClass object : o) {
        System.out.println(object);
    }
}

public static <T extends MyClass> Type getType() {
    return new TypeToken<List<T>>() {
    }.getType();
}

public static class MyClass {
    private String key;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "X{" +
                "key='" + key + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I am trying to understand how Gson works with Generics.
I am getting error in above main method.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to class org.example.Main$MyClass (com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap and org.example.Main$MyClass are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Due to Type Erasure shouldn't T be set to MyClass in the method getType(). So, Gson should have created an instance of `List<MyClass>` instead of `List<Object>`? Why T is getting treated as an Object here instead of MyClass?

I tried runnig this code but it is giving me error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that this behavior does not match normal Java type erasure. However, Gson does actually see the type variable `T` and then itself performs (incorrect) type erasure on it. Gson currently ignores the bounds of type variables and always uses `Object` instead, see [issue 2563](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/2563).

This leads to the exception you are seeing: Gson deserializes the value as `Object`, and because it is a JSON object Gson creates a `Map`, more specifically an instance of its internal `LinkedTreeMap` class.

As side note, your code contains two non type-safe actions:

- Creating a `TypeToken<List<T>>`
  As you mention at runtime due to type erasure Gson cannot know the actual type of `T`. So if your example had a `MySubclass extends MyClass`, then even if Gson's type erasure was correct you could still see a `ClassCastException` when you call `<MySubclass>getType()`. Because at runtime this information is not available so it would actually be a `TypeToken<List<T extends MyClass>>`, erased to `TypeToken<List<MyClass>>` instead of `TypeToken<List<MySubclass>>`.
  Due to that future Gson versions will [disallow capturing type variables by default](https://github.com/google/gson/pull/2376).
- Using `Gson.fromJson(..., Type)`
  These methods cannot enforce type-safety and allow you to write something like the following without causing any compilation warning or error:

  ```java
  List<MyClass> l = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<WrongClass>>() {}.getType());
  ```

  (note the mismatch `MyClass` vs. `WrongClass`)

  You should prefer the type-safe `Gson.fromJson(..., TypeToken<T>)` overloads instead, added in Gson 2.10. That is, simply omit the `TypeToken.getType()` call.

A type-safe variant of your `getType()` method could look like this:

```java
private static <T extends MyClass> TypeToken<List<T>> getType(Class<T> elementClass) {
  return (TypeToken<List<T>>) TypeToken.getParameterized(List.class, elementClass);
}
```

In Kotlin your original example could also work if you [make the type variable `reified`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) and change the return type from `Type` to `TypeToken<List<T>>`.

Comment: I don't get your 1st side point. Can you please provide me with the complete changed code?
Why would I get ClassCastException if I just add a new class to the above code extending MySubclass and assuming Gson's type erasure is correct?

Comment: @SudhanshuBansal, I have adjusted the answer and roughly changed "would see an exception" to "could see an exception when you use `<MySubclass>getType()`". I hope that makes it clearer.